# Cloud vs Local Sync

Tags: ubuntu-touch, sync

Will there be an option to sync my ubuntu phone and a desktop via usb or local wifi and not the cloud?

Comment: These options already exists for almost all phones. The more so for Ubuntu Phones.

Answer (score 0):

Crashplan is what you need. They have mobile apps for Android and iOS. You can create your backup on a local drive, a spare computer, or on the CrashPlan servere. The first 2 are free, the 3rd is an affordable $10/month.